# assigning complex type into another complex type, not throwing error

Tags: typescript

I have an two classes (`Computer`, `Mobile`) which both implement the interface `Calculator`. When I created two objects for Computer and Mobile , and assigned the Mobile object to the Computer variable, I think it should throw an error, because these 2 objects are different objects. But it is working fine:

```
let cmp1: Computer = new Computer();

let cmp3: Mobile = new Mobile();

cmp1 = cmp3 // Should error to my mind, but is allowed by TS?
```

Why does TypeScript allow the assignment of `cmp3` to `cmp1`?

Comment: Without the definitions of `Computer` and `Mobile` it is difucult to say what the issue is. You are probably running intro structural typing where two types are assignable if their structure is the same

Comment: Please consider editing the code here to constitute a [mcve] as described in the guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  It does sound like you might not be used to structural typing (see [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-prevent-two-types-from-being-structurally-compatible) for some ideas)